# How to add TAGS for Azure DNS record set created for DNS Recordset

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-dns

We are creating Pvt DNS Record using powershell command as part of our CI/CD and we are struggling here to find on how we can assign a TAG to the DNS Record created and the DNS config as the powershell command doesnt have -Tag as parameter.

Following is the command line for creating a recordset but dont have a way to Tag this resource
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.privatedns/new-azprivatednsrecordset?view=azps-6.2.0#examples

The reason to tag the resource set is because of the Azure policy we have in place to have minimum tags required and the compliance is complaining for this DNS recordset missing Tags.

any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Azure DNS Zones support tags but resource records do not.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley but the Azure resource Tag policy complains about resources missing required Tags ... May be then this is Microsoft Bug?

Comment: I do not know. Create a bug report and see what the response is. This could be a bug or a feature implemented with one service waiting for the other service to release the feature (resource record tags).

Comment: yep, I think I will have to get bug opened, as the DENY policy on the Tags is not allowing the resource record to be create in the DNS Zone as it is unable to find a Tag.